# Selenium-Wire isn't working with proxy (python)

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, seleniumwire

lately my python script just stopped working and I have no clue why. Maybe anyone of you have an idea.
There is the code:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
options = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': 'http://username:password@ip:port',
        'https': 'https://username:password@ip:port'
    }
}

driver = webdriver.Chrome(seleniumwire_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.inputanywebsite.com")
```

It worked well for a few month and suddendly stopped working. Now Google Chrome outputs the error: ERR_TIMED_OUT, but only if I am using a proxy. I tried multiple proxys, but they don't work with seleniumwire. On other machines they are fine.

btw, i am using a raspberry to run the code
and sorry for my english

Thank you and have a great day :)